# How to configure maven fail-never in pom file?

Tags: java, maven

I want to configure the tests to *not* stop execution even in case of error and try to re-run the test in case of any issue.

I use maven 3.6 to run the tests by typing

```
mvn clean verify -fn -Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=2
```

Where `fn` is a shortcut for `--fail-never`

How can i do the same by creating a profile in the `pom.xml` file?

According to https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html
I've tried to use

```
<configuration>
<argLine>
-Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=2
</argLine>
</configuration>
```

in profile part.
However, I have an issue with `-fn` part - when I try to add it to argLine, it complains that it is not recognized.

Comment: `<configuration><rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount></configuration>`

Comment: `-fn` is a maven flag. Maven runs failsafe. By the time failsafe would apply that, it's too late. Are you sure that flag's even what you want? It means even code that fails to compile will "succeed". If you only want to ignore failing tests, you shouldn't be using `-fn` anyway

Comment: @Michael #Michael should I use your configuration instead of what I provided or add it to current argLine?

Comment: Use it instead of yours

Comment: If tests fail you should fix those tests. rerunning is an indicator that those test are simply lying .. apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade your Maven version to most recent 3.8.6... (3.6.X is simply old!)

Comment: @khmarbaise But what if tested application sometimes returns 500, because of the timeouts? Yes, sure, I could add logic to the tests - repeat try in case of response 500, but I could also rerun the tests.

Comment: You should figure out why it returns sometimes the 500 code...